# Получение данных из MYSQL php

Tags: php, mysqli, get

Из бд нужно вытащить id, для $_GET запроса, чтобы показывать нужное изображение. Сам запрос получается пустым, не знаю как справить.

```
$handle = opendir('./img');     //Читаем файлы из папки /img/
while ($check = readdir($handle)) { 
    global $bd;
    $id_query = "SELECT id FROM images";
    $img_id = mysqli_query($id_query, $bd);
    echo $img_id;
    if ($check == '.' || $check == '..') continue;  
    makeThumbnail('img/'.$check,'testdir/'.$check,200,200);
    if (isset($_GET['img']) && $_GET['img'] == $img_id ) {      
?>
    <a href="/">
        <img src="img/<?=$check?>">
    </a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="/?img=<?=$img_id?>">
        <img src="testdir/<?=$check?>">
    </a>
<?php
}



}
closedir($handle);
```

При выводе $img_id

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы перепутали [параметры](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php) местами, должно быть:

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

В вашем случае:

```
$img_id = mysqli_query($bd, $id_query);
```

Comment: По началу я также подумал, но перепроверил в мануале + на практике выдало Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Comment: @Lolik123 надо не думать, а читать документацию.

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string, все правильно т.к. $img_id это _mysqli_result_ . _$img_id = mysqli_query($bd, $id_query); var_dump($img_id->fetch_array());_

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "33" ["id"]=> string(2) "33" }

Comment: _$img_id = mysqli_query($bd, $id_query); $img_id = $img_id->fetch_array(); $img_id = $img_id['id'];_